# USB Floppy drive for a 3.5" regular FDD bay

Tags: usb, floppy

I am going to be ripping out my old fan controller, and putting in a larger one in a lower bay; since I've lost the faceplate for the 3.5" FDD bay it is currently occupying, I'd like to play a USB floppy drive in there (so it doesn't look like an eye sore, with the gaping hole and all). Plus I occasionally use floppies for odd jobs, so it all works out.

The problem I am running into, of course, is that my choices seem to be a slimline USB floppy drive (which is too small for the bay), or a 3.5" drive which doesn't use USB (having looked closely at a number of combo drives (floppy + memory card), I've noticed that they all seem to sport a FDD connector, which needs to be connected to use the floppy drive; pure WTF from my standpoint).

I actually wouldn't mind a slimline drive if someone can find a way to secure it inside a 3.5" bay.

And yes, I am running Windows 7 64-bit, with all the driver fun that may entail.

So, are there any old-timers out there who have run into this problem before and solved it? Or anyone younger who wants to take a crack at it?

Comment: How slim? I'm assuming you've already looked into [mounting brackets](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816215157) that can be used to install 2.5" drives in 3.5" bays?

Comment: Something like this one: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16821105004

Comment: Ok, I am getting closer: http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=YD-8U10-2. That an internal USB floppy drive, albeit a slim version, which would require some work to fit, if they had it in stock. Now I need to find someone who actually has one.